# Run function in the background

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, notifications, background

i have a function that show a notification at specific date (calendar app and remainder)
i want the function to work in background so even when the user close the app or restart the phone he still will get the notification

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
fun go (view: View){
    Handler().postDelayed({
        Notify
            .with(this)
            .content { // this: Payload.Content.Default
                title = "New dessert menu"
                text = "The Cheesecake Factory has a new dessert for you to try!"
            }
            .show()
    }, 3000)
}
```

}

i will convert the date to milli sec then write it insted of 3000

Comment: Probably you'd like to use [Android Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Answer (score -2):

Declare a new Handler as follows:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then call handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000) from inside and outside the runnable.

Comment: This is not a question in java. A lambda is receiver of runnable in the case of OP. These are exact same code.